# Asterisk server with two connections

Tags: networking, centos, asterisk

I need that configuartion
[image]

It works, but with only one connection, with eth0
[image]

Or with only mobile broadband
[image]

I searched for it, but found only forwardind/routing solutions. How i can see asterisk will recieve all traffic(PPP and TCP) and redirect it by rules in extensions.conf, Linux should not routing it, just work with two connections.

Asterisk PPP IP - 31.....
         LAN IP - 192.168.1.100 / 255.255.255.0 /gateway 192.168.1.1
Gate LAN IP - 192.168.1.1

if eth0 active, mobile broadband active too, but dont working. even if set up mobile first and than up eth0.

[image]

Using CentOS 6.5 with GNOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concept of a default gateway presumes that in one FIB there can be only one default gateway at a time (yeah, I know this is a bit of simplification, but it's true for a given task). Since we are considering one application - *, you cannot use multiple FIBs. So, you need to set up a proper routing (static either dynamic) so different sip peers will be served through different channels.

I suggest the easiest way would be setting up different routes for different known peers. But keep in mind that your * is behind a NAT - so this installation will be overcomplicated - you will face RTP issues on a next step. I strongly advise you to avoid this approach and use public addresses on a *, with proper filtering.

Comment: thanks. I make another configuration, like a first pic, but cut WAN connection through Gate, now i have a locall network and WAN gate with PPP and it works!)